# How to conditionally display a material-ui breadcrumb within a component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, breadcrumbs

I'm using mui breadcrumbs within my react app and unsure why I am not seeing the second separator as part of my `<MyBreadcrumb />` component.

I am also trying to conditionally display my breadcrumb list but I think now that this could be the issue as it's also placing each breadcrumb item on separate lines.

The main contents looks as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Breadcrumbs from '@mui/material/Breadcrumbs';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function MyBreadcrumb() {
const { instrument, name } = useParams();
    
return (
  <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <Link to={"/"}>
      Home
    </Link>
    { !instrument ? (
      <Typography color="text.primary">{name}</Typography>
    ) : (
    <>
      <Link to={-1}>
        Musician
      </Link>
      <Typography color="text.primary">{name} - {instrument}</Typography>
    </>
    )}
  </Breadcrumbs> 
 )
}
```

Basically if `instrument` is undefined then I expect to see the following breadcrumb menu:

`Home / Tom`

Otherwise if `instrument` has a value, I then expect to see the following breadcrumb menu:

`Home / Musician / Bob - guitar`

I believe the issue with the second separator not appearing is because I'm not sure how to conditionally display my breadcrumb menu based on the above rules.

Comment: I can't reproduce the case, it works exactly as you want on this sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-f4iu3d

perhaps, can you provide the exact version of mui and react-router ?

Comment: @DavidYappeter - I've actually added more info into my issue as I am attempting to display my breadcrumb menu based on a condition and having troubles at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the DOM element, I found something interesting. I have a quick fix for this, but not the best answer I think.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-fn21v1

```
import * as React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Breadcrumbs from "@mui/material/Breadcrumbs";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const instrument = true ? "guitar" : undefined;
  const name = "Tom";

  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
        {!instrument && <Typography color="text.primary">{name}</Typography>}
        {/* OLD */}
        {/* {instrument && (
          <>
            <Link to={-1}>Musician</Link>
            <Typography color="text.primary">
              {name} - {instrument}
            </Typography>
          </>
        )} */}

        {/* NEW */}
        {instrument && <Link to={-1}>Musician</Link>}
        {instrument && (
          <Typography color="text.primary">
            {name} - {instrument}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </Breadcrumbs>
    </>
  );
}
```

So the quick fix is to seperate the `Musician` and `{name} - {instrument}` element to a different conditional rendering.

DOM screenshot with `OLD` code:
[image]

DOM screenshot with `NEW` code:
[image]

As you can see on `OLD` code, when we wrap the 2 elements with `<>...</>`, MUI will convert it into 1 list instead of 2, and meanwhile on the `NEW` code that we seperate the conditional rendering, MUI generate 2 lists.

I don't know what happen under the hood with MUI, but hope this little quick fix can help.